# firebase where query not functioning

Tags: javascript, firebase, firebase-realtime-database, google-cloud-firestore

I'm trying to run the following query:

```
   const getAttendCount = fDB.ref(`organization/${uid}`);
   const query = getAttendCount.where('lastAttendanceCount', 'array-contains', date)
   .then(snapshot => console.log(snapshot.val()))
```

I get this error:

I have these values:

```
2020-02-11-PM: 
128
2020-02-16-AM: 
158
2020-02-16-PM: 
164
```

In the example above I wanted to get the records for 02-16 am and pm.  So my solution was to do. `where('lastAttendanceCount', 'array-contains', date)`

```
UnhandledPromiseRejectionWarning: TypeError: getAttendCount.where is not a function
```

Obviously I'm doing something wrong but not sure what.

Comment: What **exactly** are you expecting this code to do?  It looks to me like you're mixing up Firestore and Realtime Database APIs.  They are two different database products with different APIs.

Comment: I'm trying to run a query where I can get where array contains but yes it's in firebase real time database.

Comment: I just updated the question with more info @DougStevenson

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You're mixing up the APIs for two different database products.

Realtime Database doesn't have a `where()` method.  That's only used with Firestore.  If you want to query Realtime Database, you need to identify the node that you want to query, add an ordering to it, and use `once()` to fetch the results, as shown in the [documentation](https://firebase.google.com/docs/database/web/lists-of-data).  I suggest reviewing it.